Integer sequences with a periodic pattern
Let $A$ and $B$ be two different integers. Let $S$ be a finite integer sequence with exactly $n_A$ $A$s and $n_B$ $B$s. By repeating $S$ infinitely many times we obtain an infinite integer sequence $P$.
Let $X$ be { $x$ | There always exists at least one successive subsequence in $P$ with exactly $x$ $A$s and $ \lfloor{ (n_A+n_B)/2}\rfloor - x$ $B$s }.
Can anyone tell me any/all element(s) of $X$? Thank you!

If $x$ is a so-called Sturmian sequence, then $X$ has at most 2 elements. One nice construction of $x$ is the following. Set $A=0$, $B=1$ and let $\alpha=n_B/(n_A+n_B)$. Now define a sequence $x(i)$ by $x(i)=\lfloor (i+1)\alpha \rfloor - \lfloor i\alpha\rfloor$. Then it's easy to check that every block of length $\ell$  has either $\lfloor \ell\alpha\rfloor $ or $\lceil \ell\alpha\rceil$ 1's.

Let $\alpha=n_A/(n_A+n_B)$ and $L=\lfloor (n_A+n_B)/2\rfloor$. Then $X=\{s_-,s_+\}$ where
$s_-=\lfloor \alpha L\rfloor$ and $s_+=\lceil\alpha L\rceil$.
First we show that for any sequence $P$ as described, there are subsequences of length $L$ with $s_\pm$ A's. Let $f(j)=\#\text{$A$'s in }P_j,\ldots, P_{j+L-1}$. Rearranging the sum shows $(f(0)+\ldots + f(n_A+n_B-1))/(n_A+n_B)=\alpha L$. Hence there are $j,j'$'s such that $f(j)\le \alpha L$ and $f(j')\ge \alpha L$. Since $|f(i+1)-f(i)|\le 1$ for each $i$, there are $j_\pm$ such that $f(j_-)=\lfloor \alpha L\rfloor$ and $f(j_+)=\lceil\alpha L\rceil$.
Next, we construct a sequence $P$ showing that $X$ contains no other values. Let $P_i=\lfloor (i+1)\alpha \rfloor -\lfloor i\alpha\rfloor$, so that $P_i$ is a sequence of 0's and 1's. Notice that $P_{i+(n_A+n_B)}=P_i$ so that $P_i$ has the required periodicity. By telescoping, for any $\ell$,
$P_i+\ldots + P_{i+\ell-1}=\lfloor (i+\ell)\alpha\rfloor -\lfloor i\alpha\rfloor$ (**).
In particular $P_{n_A+n_B-1}+\ldots + P_0=\lfloor (n_A+n_B)\alpha\rfloor = n_A$, so that $P$ has the correct frequency of $A$'s.
Using the fact that $\lfloor t+A\rfloor-\lfloor t\rfloor\in \{\lfloor A\rfloor,
\lceil A\rceil\}$, for any $t$, (**) shows that in any block of length $L$, the number of $A$'s is either $\lfloor L\alpha\rfloor$ or
$\lceil L\alpha\rceil$ as required.
(The sequence $P$ constructed above is a periodic Sturmian sequence by the way. Besides this, one can construct aperiodic Sturmian sequences using an irrational $\alpha$. These sequences have many beautiful properties.)
One more thing: you could ask a version of this question where the sub-blocks are required to be of any fixed integer length, $\ell$ say. The answer is the same: in that case, $X=\{\lfloor \alpha\ell\rfloor,\lceil\alpha\ell\rceil\}$, with exactly the same proof.

It seems that this is a partial answer. Maybe $n_A+n_B$ is an odd number, not an even number.

I made a trivial modification, changing the definition of $L$. Nothing else differs.

For example, set $n_A=12$ and $n_B=11$, according to your answer $X={ \lfloor 6 \rfloor, \lceil 6 \rceil }$, but correct answer is $X={5,6}$. @Anthony Quas

Sorry. I made a correction earlier this morning on my phone, but it was not registered. I believe the version there now is correct.
